# Como simplificar este código repetitivo de JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo este codigo de JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    //00
    $("#videoLeccion_00_1").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_00_2").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_00_3").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_00_4").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/04_SS_Cantar_FA_00.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_00_5").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/05_SS_Escuchar _SOL y FA_00.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_00_6").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/06_SS_Cantar _SOL y FA_00.webm");
    });

    //00_a
    $("#videoLeccion_0a_1").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00_a.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_0a_2").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00_a.webm");
    });
    $("#videoLeccion_0a_3").on("click", function() {
        $("#video").attr("src", "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00_a.webm");
    });
```

Notese que cambia el path en cada repetición

Como pueden ver es el mismo código pero se repite muchas veces, cada ID es un elemento li en un navbar

```html
<li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">00</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_1">Video 1</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_2">Video 2</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_3">Video 3</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_4">Video 4</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_5">Video 5</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_6">Video 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

¿Como podría simplificarlo? Podría usar Angular TypeScript EcmaScript 6 o algo así ?

Comment: Define simplificar :P

Comment: Con simplificar me refiero a poder inyectar el path en forma de variable para no tener que repetir tantas veces el mismo código jquery o algo así

Answer (score 9):

Temas elementales para los nuevos programadores:

1. Aprender los fundamentos lo mejor que puedan, ésto les ahorrará muchísimo tiempo en temas de diseño de arquitectura tanto en infraestructura como de código.
2. Aprender de diversas fuentes, invertir tiempo y recursos en buenos instructores, materiales. Que nadie diga que le falta dinero que hasta Hardvard, Stanford y el mismísimo M.I.T tienen cursos libres.
3. Practicar y seguir practicando.
4. Tomar a bien los comentarios, que lo único que se busca es ayudar a que expandan su manera de pensar.
5. Leer la pregunta tantas veces como sea posible antes de publicarla... "¿Como podría simplificarlo? Podría usar Angular TypeScript EcmaScript 6 o algo así ?" Para lo que hay detallado, es como querer matar una mosca con una bomba nuclear.

Sé que tienes la capacidad de hacer funcionar el siguiente código:

```js
 $(".myvideo").on("click", function(element) {
    console.log(element.target.id);
    var rutaBase = "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/";
    var nombreArchivo = $(element.target).data("archivo");
    console.log(nombreArchivo);
    $("#video").attr("src", rutaBase+nombreArchivo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">00</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a data-archivo="03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm" id="videoLeccion_00_1">Video 1</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_2">Video 2</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_3">Video 3</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_4">Video 4</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_5">Video 5</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a id="videoLeccion_00_6">Video 6</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Recomendaciones

A leer la documentación del mismo Jquery y los fundamentos de JavaScript en la MDN (Mozilla Developer Network).

Comment: Fredy completa los `data`, sale bien solamente en el primero, en los otros sale `undefined`...

Comment: Buen día @A.Cedano, lo hice adrede para que los usuarios analicen el código, veo que el usuario está empezando a programar y el panorama lo tiene borroso, así que es buena oportunidad para ayudar a subir su nivel de "detective de bugs y de desarrollador".

Comment: Muy creativo de tu parte Fredy y totalmente válido.

Comment: Gracias mi estimado, valoro mucho por tu colaboración constante con el sitio, un abrazo :D

Answer (score 3):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Primero me voy a permitir poner una tras otra todas las URL que estás usando:

```
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/04_SS_Cantar_FA_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/05_SS_Escuchar _SOL y FA_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/06_SS_Cantar _SOL y FA_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00_a.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00_a.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00_a/03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00_a.webm
```

Lo hago para poder hacerte cuatro críticas en el estilo de URL que estás implementando:

- Trata de hacer una convención de nombres uniforme: no entiendo por qué saltas de un estilo `00/00/06_SS_` a un estilo `00/00_a/02_SS_` . Tendrás tus razones, pero yo trataría de guardar un estilo uniforme.
- No usaría mayúsculas en la URL
- No usaría espacios en la URL (en las pruebas verás que cuando hay espacios son cambiados por `%20` debido a la norma RFC y esto te puede traer algunas dificultades).
- No repetiría dos veces la palabra *sistema serna*  en la URL. Esto, aparte de feo, redundante, más largo, te puede traer consecuencias a nivel de SEO.

Yo implementaría una convención como esta:

```
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/01_ss_escuchar_sol_00.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/a/01_ss_escuchar_sol_00a.webm
```

Incluso, si no son archivos para descargar, se podría pensar en una convención así:

```
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/escuchar/01_sol.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/a/escuchar/01_sol.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/cantar/01_sol.webm
assets/sistema_serna2/modulo1/videos/nivel/00/a/cantar/01_sol.webm
```

A veces se puede pensar que esto no tiene demasiada importancia. Si observas, las URL escritas así están aptas por ejemplo para ser usadas como puntos de entrada en un sistema tipo API, WebService, RESTFull ... Quizá no sea tu caso, pero aunque no lo sea ahora mismo nunca se sabe, las cosas evolucionan y cuando lo hagan ya tienes un orden establecido que te permitirá adaptar el código sin modificar lo organización de los recursos. Además, son URLs mucho más intuitivas, más cortas y menos susceptibles de posibles errores o problemas.

También, el usuario sabrá que, para pasar de `escuchar` a `cantar` la misma nota, podrá cambiar el *verbo*  en la `URL`. O que para pasar de una nota a otra, podrá cambiar el nombre de la nota en la URL (incluso se podría quitar el número incremental que da nombre a cada nota si fuera el caso).

---

Pasando ahora a la forma de automatizar el código un poco más, hay muchas maneras de hacerlo. Te muestro una basada en la realidad de tu convención de nombres en las URL. Si usaras una convención más uniforme la automatización sería mucho más fácil, pero eso ya no depende más que de ti.

Mi código es parecido al de @freddyfx, con la diferencia de que yo agrego otro elemento `data` para las sub-carpetas, así el código queda más automatizado y sirve tanto para las vídeos del grupo `00` como para los vídeos del grupo `00_a` o cualquier otro que esté en otra sub-carpeta.

```js
$(".myvideo").on("click", function(e) {
  var basePath = "assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/";
  var subFolder = $(e.target).data("subfolder");
  var fileName = $(e.target).data("file");
  var videoPath=basePath+subFolder+"/"+fileName;
  console.log(`Esta es la ruta que se establecerá: \n${videoPath}`);
  var $video=$("#video");
  $video.prop("src", videoPath);
  /*
    *Dado que no es una ruta absoluta, en este caso
    *se agregará la ruta de stacksnippets
    *No se verá el vídeo, como el de la flor
    *porque el sitio no soporta webm y porque no
    *se está sobre el sitio en sí
    *si fuera mp4 y tuviera la ruta del sitio completa sí se vería
  */
  console.log("src del elemento: \n"+$video.prop('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">00</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#">
      <a data-subfolder="00" data-file="01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00.webm" id="videoLeccion_00_1">Video 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00" data-file="02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_2">Video 2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00" data-file="03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_3">Video 3</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00" data-file="04_SS_Cantar_FA_00.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_4">Video 4</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00" data-file="05_SS_Escuchar _SOL y FA_00.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_5">Video 5</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00" data-file="06_SS_Cantar _SOL y FA_00.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_6">Video 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<hr />
<li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">00_a</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#">
      <a data-subfolder="00_a" data-file="01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00_a.webm" id="videoLeccion_00a_1">Video 1</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00a" data-file="02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00_a.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_2">Video 2</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown-item myvideo" href="#"><a  data-subfolder="00a" data-file="03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00_a.webm"  id="videoLeccion_00_3">Video 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<img id="video" width="250" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4"
            type="video/webm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Hola Ronald, aquí te propongo una alternativa,
    En el href de tu etiqueta <a> que se encuentra  dentro de <li> puedes colocar el nombre los videos-->

    <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">00</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_1" href="01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00.webm">Video 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_2" href="02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00.webm">Video 2</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_3" href="03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm">Video 3</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_4"  href="04_SS_Cantar_FA_00.webm">Video 4</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_5" href="05_SS_Escuchar _SOL y FA_00.webm">Video 5</a</li>
        <li class="dropdown-item"><a id="videoLeccion_00_6" href="06_SS_Cantar _SOL y FA_00.webm">Video 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <video id="reproductor" src=""></video>

    <script>

        //javascript
        //guardamos la ruta del video
        const ruta="assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/00/";
        //seleccionamos la etiqueta html <ul> con la clase dropdown-menu
        var lista=document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu")

        // agregamos el evnto click a lista
            lista.addEventListener('click',function(e){
              //para evitar que <a> tome como ruta y se abra la pagina con los nombres del video en el href, prevenimos la funcion por defecto de href.e.prevent.default
              e.preventDefault();
              // con target capturamos el click a la etiqueta <a>
               if(e.target.localName=="a")
                 {
                   //aqui capturamos el atributo href con el nombre del video
                   var video=document.querySelector("#reproductor")
                   var nombrevideo=e.target.getAttribute("href");
                   //ahora a la etiqueta video en su atributo src colocamos la ruta + 
               el nombre del video
                    video.src=`${ruta}${nombrevideo}`
                 }

            })
    </script>
```

Por favor, tome en cuenta los comentarios anteriores:
1: tomate un tiempo para revisar los fundamentos de diseño, arquitectura.
2: uniformiza las urls,

Answer (score 0):

> En **JS** creamos **3 variables**, para la cadena completa que conformara el src final.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".video").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var video = $(this).data('video');
        var src = 'assets/sistema_serna2/SISTEMA SERNA_I/VIDEOS/Nivel_00/' + id + '/' + video;
        $("#video").attr("src", src);
    });
});
```

> En **HTML** se reemplaza el id por la clase video para **click** de *jQuery*, y
>   se agregan los **data-id** y **data-video**.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="01_SS_Escuchar_SOL_00.webm">
            Video 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="02_SS_Cantar_SOL_00.webm">
            Video 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="03_SS_Escuchar_FA_00.webm">
            Video 3
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="04_SS_Cantar_FA_00.webm">
            Video 4
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="05_SS_Escuchar _SOL y
            FA_00.webm">Video 5
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a class="video" data-id="00" data-video="06_SS_Cantar _SOL y
            FA_00.webm">Video 6
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```